# react Redirect is

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

so since Redirect is a component which should be returned by the render I am trying to redirect my user to some page after verifying that he is authenticated , and for some reason it's not redirecting.
I would rather not to use useHistory since im doin a protected Route for comps and not handling an event.
What am I missing out ?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {

const {isAuthenticated,loading} = useSelector(state => state.auth);

return (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => !isAuthenticated && !loading ?
    (<Redirect to='/login' />) :
    (<Component {...props} />)} />
 )
}


export default PrivateRoute
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be

> **import { BrowserRouter as Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";**

like this:

> **import { BrowserRouter , Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";**

Comment: Haha I have no idea how I missed this , but I'm really glad I got your help.
 thanks for the effort and time buddy.
 keep up the good work

Comment: Haha, It's ok buddy

Answer (score 0):

BrowserRouter was imported as Redirect!
instead of importing Redirect alongside the BrowserRouter from react-router-dom

before

```
import { BrowserRouter as Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

after

```
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```